# APNS not working, SSL Broken Pipe & bad write retry

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

I'm developing apple application for my company,

I'm working on server side using PHP, laravel framework to send message to APNS.

For testing, I use hardcode device token.
I get it work on one device that I hardcode.

so I'm advance to function that send apns, a device token that requested in function.
so when I call this function, it get device token from database and send to apns.

I get error

```
fwrite(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1409F07F:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_PENDING:bad write retry
```

and

```
fwrite(): SSL: Broken pipe
```

I change the code back to first testing, but it does not work like before.

anyone have idea what I made wrong or did I made a mistake in my request?

for note this is my code

```
    $apnsServer = 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195';

    $privateKeyPassword = 'my_private_key';

    $id = $request->input('id');
    $message = "message_here";

    $userSelected = User::select('device_token')->where('id', $id)->first();
    $deviceToken = str_replace(' ', '', $userSelected['device_token']);

    $pushCertAndKeyPemFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'my_certificate.pem';
    $stream = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($stream, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $privateKeyPassword);
    stream_context_set_option($stream, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $pushCertAndKeyPemFile);
    $connectionTimeout = 30;
    $connectionType = STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT;
    $connection = stream_socket_client($apnsServer, $errorNumber, $errorString, $connectionTimeout, $connectionType, $stream);

    if (!$connection){
        echo "Failed to connect to the APNS server. Error = $errorString <br/>"; 
        exit;
    }else{
        echo "Successfully connected to the APNS. Processing...</br>";
    }
    $messageBody['aps'] = array('alert' => $message, 'sound' => 'default', 'badge' => 1);

    $payload = json_encode($messageBody);
    $notification = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
    $wroteSuccessfully = fwrite($connection, $notification, strlen($notification));

    if (!$wroteSuccessfully){
        echo "Could not send the message<br/>";
    } else {
        echo "Successfully sent the message<br/>"; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

After some research, i've found my problem.

1. When our server send PUSH message to APNS, there is response error need to check for every request.
   After check error, i get error message 8, invalid token
2. When using development certificate, and there is user register using development application, they get device token
   but when you change to production, you have to change production certificate and registered user need to get new device token to make PUSH notification work

because device token you get in development apps, will not work with production certificate..

it's totally my mistake to miss important things..